# facebook passing argument in url

Tags: php, facebook

I want to pass a facebook userid as an argument in my url.

It looks like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo 'single_picture.php?argument=' . $picture_id . '&hus=' . $user_profile['id'] ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote!">
</form>
```

and I retrieve it with this:

```
$picture_id = $_GET['argument'];
$fbargument = $_GET["hus"];

echo "\npicture_id: ";
echo $picture_id;

echo '<br />';

echo "\$fbargument: ";
echo $fbargument;
```

The first argument works, but I can't get the second argument to work :(

I tried storing the userid in another variable and sending it, but no luck either.

I am outputting all the data to the screen, to make sure I have a userid, and I can see that works.

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
echo "id: " . $user_profile['id'];
```

This print out my ID, when I log in.

Comment: you can store it in the session but secure wise it's not recomended.

Comment: I would use Google chrome's inspect element to double check the request that is being sent out. You can see the GET variables and their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now i realize, you dont need the form.
Just do and ajax function and pass the arguments there:

eg:

```
<input type="hidden" id="argument" value="<?= $picture_id?>">
<input type="hidden" id="hus" value="<?= $user_profile['id']?>">

$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { 
    var argument = $("#argument").val(),
        hus = $("#hus").val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: 'url.php',
        data: { argument: argument , hus: hus },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(e) {
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No luck :( I am having a hard time figuring it out, since I found some really simple examples, but for some reason argument 1 always work, but hus never works :/

Comment: its strange. try checking the argument value with firebug, and post here the result.